# Magento 2.3 debug Path Hints dont show

Tags: magento2

I enabled Magento's frontend debug path hints but they are not showing.

```
Infos:
- Magento 2.3.0 with Porto Theme
- Php 7.2
- Already tested to change Magento Single Store MOde and Multistore Mode
- Already made di:compile
- Already tested blank Dev IP and my own IP
- Already changed Magento Modes default and developer
- Already cleaned and flushed the cache
- Already removed generated and pub static folders
```

But still, the red *Hintlines* in Frontend don't show up.

Answer (score 12):

Please follow the following steps-

```
Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Store View: Default Store View->
Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront --> Yes
Enable Hints for Storefront with URL Parameter --> Yes
Parameter Value --> magento
```

After setting this, check on frontend by putting param (?templatehints=magento) in url like this -

http://localhost/test/index.php?templatehints=magento

Answer (score 0):

You should use below steps:-

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
2. In the left panel, expand Advanced and choose Developer.
3. Expand [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx4lu.png) the Debug section and do the following:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4vt9.png)
4. After that you should clean cache.

OR

You can use below commands

For eable
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable

For disable
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable

Then clean cache
php bin/magento clean:cache